# Custom design on Google plus

Tags: google-plus

How can I give the google+1 button on my site a custom look, similar to the 5 star london site http://www.5ivestarlondon.com/

Answer (score 2):

> For buttons that may be rendered by the Publisher, such as the Sharing Link, the Publisher must use only the official Google-provided icon or a plain text and link combination.

http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/policy.html